# Understanding CT and ADC resolution

Tags: adc

Reading [this article](https://resources.altium.com/pcb-design-blog/current-transformers-how-to-project) I'm trying to understand this fragment where they are using a 1000:1 CT, with 0.1 V/A for a 100 ohm load.

> A simple 12bit ADC will give us 2^12, or 4096 possible values. Applied
> to a 3300mV range, this gives us a resolution of about 0.8mV. The load
> pictured above has a total peak-to-peak voltage span of 1219mV, and
> should be about a 4.5-4.7A load. The 1219mV give us a possible 1523
> values for the voltage displayed at our calculated resolution, which
> translates to about 3mA per ADC value when using our 100 ohm load
> resistor (remember: it’s RMS!).

I know that 0.8 mV comes from 3.3/4096. I think there's an error with 1523 value, since I get Adc = (1.219*4096)/3.3 = 1513.

My question is: how is the ratio *3 mA per ADC value* derived?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4.6 A gives about 1219 mV.

1219 mV ---> 1513 counts

---

4.6 A ---> 1513 counts

??? ---> 1 count?

---

**Ans**: ~3.02 mA